# Docker remote api don't restart after my computer restart

Tags: docker, docker-api

Last week I struggled to make my `docker remote api` working. As it is running on VM, I have not restart my VM since then. Today I finally restarted my VM and it is not working any more (docker and docker-compose are working normally, but not `docker remote api`). My docker init file looks like this: `/etc/init/docker.conf`.

```
description     "Docker daemon"

start on filesystem and started lxc-net
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

script
    /usr/bin/docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -d
end script

# description "Docker daemon"

# start on (filesystem and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
# stop on runlevel [!2345]
# limit nofile 524288 1048576
# limit nproc 524288 1048576

respawn

kill timeout 20
.....
.....
```

Last time I made setting indicated here [this](http://blog.trifork.com/2013/12/24/docker-from-a-distance-the-remote-api/)

I tried `nmap` to see if `port 4243` is opened.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ nmap 0.0.0.0 -p-

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-10-12 23:49 CEST
Nmap scan report for 0.0.0.0
Host is up (0.000046s latency).
Not shown: 65531 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
43978/tcp open  unknown
44672/tcp open  unknown
60366/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.11 seconds
```

as you can see, the port 4232 is not opened.

when I run:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo -e "GET /images/json HTTP/1.0\r\n" | nc -U
This is nc from the netcat-openbsd package. An alternative nc is available
in the netcat-traditional package.
usage: nc [-46bCDdhjklnrStUuvZz] [-I length] [-i interval] [-O length]
      [-P proxy_username] [-p source_port] [-q seconds] [-s source]
      [-T toskeyword] [-V rtable] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_protocol]
      [-x proxy_address[:port]] [destination] [port]
```

I run this also:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo docker -H=tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -d
flag provided but not defined: -d
See 'docker --help'.
```

I restart my computer  many times and try a lot of things with no success. 
I already have a group named docker and my user is in:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ groups $USER
ubuntu : ubuntu adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker
```

Please tel me what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your startup script contains an invalid command:

```
/usr/bin/docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -d
```

Instead you need something like:

```
/usr/bin/docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243
```

As of 1.12, this is now (but `docker daemon` will still work):

```
/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243
```

**Please note that this is opening a port that gives remote root access without any password to your docker host.**

Anyone that wants to take over your machine can run `docker run -v /:/target -H your.ip:4243 busybox /bin/sh` to get a root shell with your filesystem mounted at /target. If you'd like to secure your host, follow [this guide to setting up TLS certificates](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/).

Comment: Thanks to you BMIitch, I am aware of security. But this was for test. I am planning to use 127.0.0.1 and dockerode to handle start and stop.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found [www.ivankrizsan.se](https://www.ivankrizsan.se/2016/05/18/enabling-docker-remote-api-on-ubuntu-16-04/) and it is working find now. Thanks to this guy (or girl) ;). 
This settings work for me on ubuntu 16.04. Here is how to do :

- Edit this file `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` and replace the line `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://` with 
  `ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243`
- Save the file
- restart with :`sudo service docker restart`
- Test with :    `curl http://localhost:4243/version`
- Result: you should see something like this:

  `{"Version":"1.11.0","ApiVersion":"1.23","GitCommit":"4dc5990","GoVersion" "go1.5.4","Os":"linux","Arch":"amd64","KernelVersion":"4.4.0-22-generic","BuildTime":"2016-04-13T18:38:59.968579007+00:00"}`

**Attention :** 
Remain aware that 0.0.0.0 is not good for security, for more security, you should use 127.0.0.1

Comment: Just noticed you are editing /lib/systemd in your solution, it's better to `cp /lib/systemd/system/docker.service /etc/systemd/system/docker.service`, and edit the file in /etc. You'll need a `systemctl daemon-reload` to reload the unit file into systemd. Changes to the file in /lib may be overwritten without warning on an upgrade, while your copy in /etc overrides the version in /lib.